# How to stop postgres process inside kuberenetes pod from responding

Tags: linux, postgresql, kubernetes

I have postgres running inside kubernetes pod. I want postgres to stop responding to requests to test the application behavior when postgres is offline. I cannot kill the postgres pod. I just need to disrupt the connection to postgres or suspend the postgres process. I tried kill -STOP command on the postgres process but it is not helpful. Please let me know is there any way to make the postgres to go offline for some time.

Comment: Do you use k8s service in front of your postgres pod?

Comment: Try to access to pod with https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/ and kill the postgres process as normal way

Comment: Yes I do use kubernetes service in front of the postgres pod. I tried kill -STOP pid inside the pod but it is not having any effect

Comment: You can use istio to introduce [fault injection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/fault-injection/). Otherwise i think you need to make a deployment with different main process as pod status is directly related to main process which in your case is postgres process.

Answer (score -1):

You could temporary delete the `Service` object in front of the pods,
You need to deploy and delete the service object multiple time to testing your application behavior, that the easy way...

the hard way you could use [NetworkPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/), to limit your pods connectivity

Comment: delete service does not affect already established connection. Network Policies are not supported in aws by default

Comment: why don't you just delete postgress pod if it's like that?